# How do I cope with size limits for Web Storage?

Tags: javascript, exception, cross-browser

The W3C spec for Web Storage (colloquially known as HTML5 local storage, although this is a misnomer) allows user agents to enforce a size limit, which is recommended at 5MB. According to various sources I've found around the net, a lot of modern browsers use this 5MB limit, except IE which gives 10MB.

First, I want to know, does the limit apply to the combined total of localStorage and sessionStorage, or to them individually?

Now, how do we actually cope with these limits? Is there any way to find out what the limit is for a particular browser? Is there any website which maintains statistics on the different browsers? Is an exception thrown when the browser goes over the limit? Is there a foolproof way to test for this exception "class" in different browsers?

Comment: Did you find a good answer to this?

Comment: No, not really. To make matters worse, there is one major browser (I forgot which one) which displays a dialog box if the website tries to exceed the storage limit. There is no way for the web developer to customise this message, so it will just say something like "this website is trying to exceed its storage limit" which is a very bad user experience. Due to this, my company decided not to use local storage for our use case and just use the default browser caching mechanism instead with URLs that "look like" javascript files but actually just contain dynamically generated object definitions.

Comment: I wrote a module that takes care of talking to localStorage in a way so that it never exceeds the maximum allowed, if it gets over 4mb it empties the oldest entries it has until it has gone below 3mb. also the byte quantity used at each time is updated each time the system adds or removes from it, meaning you can get the currently used byte quantity with seek time big-o 1.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no method in `localStorage` object to determine its size. However, trying to write an amount of data that exceeds storage limit will result in an exception you can catch.

Take a look at http://arty.name/localstorage.html

Basically, you can wrap the writing function in a `try...catch` block like this:

```
function write(value, name) {
    try {
        localStorage.field = value;
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, yes I did see the example on that site, and since my post, I noticed that it catches an exception. However I wondered if there's a way to test if that exception is of the right form? For example, in my browser (Firefox) the exception name is "NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED" but I think that is Firefox-specific. I think there should be some library to deal with these kinds of things!!

Comment: Also, for that site, it wasn't clear whether the quota is for both localStorage and sessionStorage, or just one or the other...